# Is there any way to exclude documents that were matched in previous function_scores in ElasticSearch?

Tags: function, elasticsearch, search, lucene

I have a list of documents for eg:

```
 { "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "title": "Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide", "authors": ["clinton gormley", "zachary tong"], "summary" : "A distibuted real-time search and analytics engine", "publish_date" : "2015-02-07", "num_reviews": 20, "publisher": "oreilly" }
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "title": "Taming Text: How to Find, Organize, and Manipulate It", "authors": ["grant ingersoll", "timothy potter", "thomas morton", "drew farris"], "summary" : "organize text using approaches such as full-text search, proper name recognition, clustering, tagging, information extraction, and summarization", "publish_date" : "2013-01-24", "num_reviews": 12, "publisher": "manning" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "title": "Elasticsearch in Action", "authors": ["radu gheorge","timothy potter", "matthew lee hinman", "roy russo"], "summary" : "build scalable search applications using Elasticsearch without having to do complex low-level programming or understand advanced data science algorithms", "publish_date" : "2015-12-03", "num_reviews": 18, "publisher": "manning" }
{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{ "title": "Solr in Action", "authors": ["trey grainger", "timothy potter"], "summary" : "Comprehensive guide to implementing a scalable search engine using Apache Solr", "publish_date" : "2014-04-05", "num_reviews": 23, "publisher": "manning" }
```

...

What I want to achieve is this:
I have 2 functions in function_score:

```
func[1] = Searches 3 docs for author "timothy potter" and assigns a weight of 10
func[2[ = Searches 3 docs for author "trey grainger" and assigns a weight of 20
```

If I use `score_mode as 'first'` all the documents matching "timothy potter" gets picked and gets weight of 10.

Instead what I want to achieve is :
If first 3 documents are matched, the rest of the docs with author "timothy potter" should get scored in the 2nd function.

Right now all the common matching docs get scored by only first function.

One solution which I thought was - Having multiple Queries in Elastic for different functions and keep excluding already matched documents in next queries.

Any way this can be achieved using funcion_score